# Google group breaks the sent-to email—how to avoid it?

Tags: google-groups, google-workspace-for-business

I have a group in my Google Enterprise account, that includes 3 other users. I need that when someone sends an email to the group (group@nonce.com), it will be sent to the individual members, but the "Sent to" address will *not* change—I need that the *sent-to* address will still show as `group@nonce.com`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups in the Gmail contact manager are not the same than Google Groups.

The groups in the Gmail contact manager will always change the group name to the list of the group members email addresses, by the other hand, Google Groups will always show the email address when it's included in TO or CC.

Ask you domain administrator to create a group in the admin.google.com or if you have access to Google Groups for Business for your domain and are allowed to do so, create a group. To do so:

1. Go to http://groups.google.com/a/yourdomain.com
2. Click on Create group
3. Follow the on screen instructions.